# Find highest number within a dynamic range R

Tags: r

I have a column in my chronologically-sorted `df` which indicates the observation (or row number) in the `df` when a certain trigger condition is met in the future, e.g. `df$condition_met <- c(NA, NA, 61, NA, ...)` - i.e. the third row of my `df` is the first occurrence where the condition is met, and it is met in row 61. (I'm not sure you even need this context!)

I want to find the maximum value in a different column (`df$high`) between the row after the row number I am in (`3+1` in this example) and the row before the condition being met (`60` in this example.)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: In some cases df$condition_met may contain an 'Inf' instead of a number. In this case, I'd like to look all the way through df$high, rather than restrict the end of the range to look in. Thank you!

Comment: I would appreciate if some sample data was provided with such issue. It will be easier for people to help.

Comment: Here is some data. Up to 70 rows (b/c first condition met in row 61) df$high <- c(0.1067,0.1069,0.1069,0.1065,0.1069,0.1069,0.1069,0.1066,0.1068,0.1068,0.1069,0.107,0.1074,0.1075,0.1075,0.1075,0.1075,0.1074,0.1074,0.1073,0.1072,0.1072,0.1072,0.1071,0.1071,0.1071,0.107,0.107,0.1072,0.1072,0.1071,0.1071,0.107,0.1068,0.1068,0.1068,0.1067,0.1066,0.1066,0.1066,0.1068,0.1069,0.1068,0.1068,0.1068,0.1067,0.1067,0.1067,0.1065,0.1064,0.1065,0.1072,0.1065,0.1061,0.106,0.106,0.106,0.1061,0.106,0.106,0.106,0.106,0.1059,0.1057,0.1058,0.1058,0.1055,0.1055,0.105,0.105)

Comment: df$condition_met <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,61,NA,NA,NA,51,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, along with the check for Infinity:

```
low_row_num <- which(!is.na(df$condition_met))
high_row_num <- as.integer(df[low_row_num, "condition_met"])

if (high_row_num == Inf) {
  max_val <- max(df$high[(low_row_num+1):length(df$high)])
} else {
  max_val <- max(df$high[(low_row_num+1):high_row_num])
}
```

The variable `max_val` being your answer.

---

Solution for the case where multiple cells satisfy `!is.na(condition_met)`:

```
max_val_and_index <- function(df, i) {
  if (is.na(df$condition_met[i])) {
    max_val <- NA
    index <- NA
  } else {
    high_row_num <- min(df[i, "condition_met"], nrow(df))
    max_val <- max(df$high[(i+1):high_row_num])
    index <- which.max(df$high[(i+1):high_row_num]) + i
  }
  result <- c("max_val" = max_val, "index" = index)
}
```

And example usage:

```
> df
   condition_met high
1:             4    4
2:            NA    1
3:             8    2
4:            NA    3
5:            NA    4
6:             8    1
7:           Inf    5
8:            NA    3
9:            NA    4
> sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) max_val_and_index(df, x))
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
max_val    3   NA    5   NA   NA    5    4   NA   NA
index      4   NA    7   NA   NA    7    9   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It does return the right answer. It returns only the one, however. I would like to see the answers for each instance in df$condition_met where it's != NA. i.e. an output that looks like c(NA, NA, .1075, NA, .... etc.) It would also be great to retrieve the row number of that highest value.

Comment: @Winston see the edit for a solution that includes the value and the index of that value for each row in the table.

Comment: where is there a (x) after the function call in sapply? i don't fully understand this. struggling to get this to work fully. It seems to be returning some NA values in "high_row_num <- min(as.integer(df[i, "condition_met"]), nrow(df))" - not sure how that's possible!

Comment: Yes you're right I shouldn't have included the `as.integer(...)` call as `as.integer(Inf)` returns `NA`. This solution should work now? The `x` in `sapply` is telling R to consider each element of the vector I'm feeding into it, in this case `1:nrow(df)` to be `x`, and supply that variable `x` to the `max_val_and_index` function as the `i` argument.